# Angularjs, watching rootScope variable to react changes via animate not working

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have the below code snippet inside my application.js ...

```
.directive('titleEffect', function($animate){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch(attrs.titleEffect, function(newVal){
            $animate.addClass(element, 'title_effect')
        })
    };

})

.animation('.title_effect', function(){
    return{
        addClass: function(element, className){
            console.log('aaa')
        }
})
```

But ng-animation addClass function is not triggered  and here is my html:

```
<h3  title-effect='globalData.currentTitle' > </h3>
```

Where currentTitle is a global data set with:

```
.run(function($rootScope){
$rootScope.globalData = {currentTitle : ''}
})
```

Comment: If I add an if statement to $watch function ---> if(newVal){$animate.addClass(element, 'title-effect')} -----  inspector logs 'aaa'  once...

Answer (score 0):

Your watch function might get called 2 times before your directive is ready. Using your code, the `.title_effect` class has been added, but not animated because it was added before it was initialized and you never removed the class. You also need to call `done()` in your animations in order to remove `ng-animate` from your element so you can change the animations.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"])

.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.titleEffect = false;
})

.directive("titleEffect", ["$animate",
  function($animate) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.titleEffect, function(newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
          $animate.addClass(element, "title_effect");
        } else {
          $animate.removeClass(element, "title_effect");
        }
      });
    };
  }
])

.animation(".title_effect", function() {
  return {
    addClass: function(element, className, done) {
      console.log('add');
      TweenMax.to(element, 0.35, {
        autoAlpha: 0,
        onComplete: done
      });
    },
    removeClass: function(element, className, done) {
      console.log('remove');
      TweenMax.to(element, 0.35, {
        autoAlpha: 1,
        onComplete: done
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.13.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
  <button ng-click="vm.titleEffect = !vm.titleEffect">Toggle</button>
  <div class="block" title-effect="vm.titleEffect"></div>
</div>
```